# Java jersey RestService ignoring @RolesAllowed

Tags: java, security, authentication, jersey

I'm trying to set up permissions in my RestService but for some reason `@RolesAllowed("user")` doesn't seem to do anything at the moment.

I filled up my SecurityContext up right and the constructor is getting called but for some reason `isUserInRole(String role)` never gets called by `RolesAllowed`. No matter if I'm a user or guest I can still access the /countries path without any errors.

My rest service:

```
@Path("/countries")
public class CountryResource {

    @RolesAllowed("user")
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String getCountries() {
        System.out.println("countries?");
        JsonArrayBuilder countries = Json.createArrayBuilder();

        for (Country c : ServiceProvider.getCountryService().getAllCountries()) 
        {
            JsonObjectBuilder jsonCountry = buildCountry(c);

            if (jsonCountry != null)
                countries.add(jsonCountry);
        }

        return countries.build().toString();
    }
}
```

My SecurityContext:

```
public class MySecurityContext implements SecurityContext {
    private String name;
    private String role;
    private boolean isSecure;

    public MySecurityContext(String name, String role, boolean isSecure) {
        System.out.println(name+role+isSecure);
        this.name = name;
        this.role = role;
    }

    public Principal getUserPrincipal() {
        System.out.println("Principal");
        return new Principal() {
            public String getName() {
                return name;
            }
        };
    }

    public boolean isUserInRole(String role) {
        System.out.println("Is user in role: "+this.role);
        return role.equals(this.role);
    }

    public boolean isSecure() {
        return isSecure;
    }

    public String getAuthenticationScheme() {
        return "Bearer";
    }
}
```

Filter:

```
@Provider
@Priority(Priorities.AUTHENTICATION)
public class AuthenticationFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {
    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestCtx) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("filter?");
        // Users are treated as guests, unless a valid JWT is provided
        boolean isSecure = requestCtx.getSecurityContext().isSecure();
        MySecurityContext msc = new MySecurityContext("Unknown", "guest", isSecure);
        // Check if the HTTP Authorization header is present and formatted
        // correctly
        String authHeader = 
            requestCtx.getHeaderString(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);
        System.out.println(authHeader);
        if (authHeader != null && authHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            // Extract the token from the HTTP Authorization header
            String token = authHeader.substring("Bearer".length()).trim();
            try {
                // Validate the token
                JwtParser parser = Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(AuthenticationResource.key);
                Claims claims = parser.parseClaimsJws(token).getBody();
                String user = claims.getSubject();
                String role = claims.get("role").toString();

                msc = new MySecurityContext(user, role, isSecure);

            } catch (JwtException | IllegalArgumentException e) {

                System.out.println("Invalid JWT, processing as guest!");
            }
        }

        System.out.println(msc);
        requestCtx.setSecurityContext(msc);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Things you need to make sure of:

1. Make sure that filter where you are setting the `SecurityContext` is annotated with `@Priority(Priorities.AUTHENTICATION)`. This is important, because filter that does the authorization has the priority `Priorities.AUTHORIZATION`, which happens *after* authentication. If you forget the add the priority, it defaults to `Priorities.USER` which is *after* all other `Priorities`. See [Filters and Interceptors: Priorities](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html#d0e9783).
2. Make sure your filter where you are setting the `SecurityContext` is registered.
3. Make sure the `RolesAllowedDynamicFeature` is registered. This is the main feature that gives you the authorization. It will register a filter with a `Priority.AUTHORIZATION`. In that filter, it will get the `SecurityContext` that you set in the previously called filter, and then grab the `@RolesAllowed` annotation and check that against the `SecurityContext#isUserInRole`

### UPDATE

To register the `RolesAllowedDynamicFeature`, if you are using a `ResourceConfig`, just call `register(RolesAllowedDynamicFeature.class)`. If you are using a web.xml, then you should add the following init-param

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
    <param-value>
        org.glassfish.jersey.server.filter.RolesAllowedDynamicFeature
    </param-value>
</init-param>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! How do I exactly register my `SecurityContext` and `RolesAllowedDynamicFeature`? I have no clue where to add the resourceconfig for example.

Comment: I also added my filter incase something is wrong there. The priority allready has been set like you said.

Comment: I'm using a web.xml. Should I add this init param to my servlet or to a new servlet? I'm getting errors in eclipse when pasting it in.

Comment: Same Jersey servlet. Right next to (after) any other init-param you might have